# Error : Property 'label' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339) in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am following below links to create simple example

https://github.com/adiathasan/mui-react-hook-form-plus

or Live example

https://mui-react-hook-form-plus.vercel.app/?path=/docs/form-context--hookformprovider

But while splitting code I am getting this error **Property 'label' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)**

When I am putting all code in same file it is working fine

**working fine demo**

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-flower-0r3hdf?file=/src/App.tsx

But when I put separate the component I am getting above error

**NOT WORKING fine**
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-sky-6b2gs8?file=/src/autpcomplete.tsx:732-744

```
export default function AutoComplete({ registerState }) {
  return (
    <HookAutoComplete
      {...registerState("movie")}
      autocompleteProps={{
        options: top100Films,
        autoHighlight: true,
        isOptionEqualToValue: ({ label }, value) => label === value.label
      }}
      textFieldProps={{
        label: "Movie",
        placeholder: "The..."
      }}
      gridProps={{
        xs: 12
      }}
      rules={{
        required: {
          message: "Required",
          value: true
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in the "working" version that all the types are allowed to be inferred because everything is internal to the component. When you create an external component you've not typed the props that are passed to your `AutoComplete` component. Ideally you'd fully type the `HookAutoComplete` props object.

Without going down the rabbit hole for how `mui-react-hook-form-plus` is exporting hooks and any type declarations from `react-hook-form` it's trivial to just type the `isOptionEqualToValue` manually.

```
interface FilmOption {
  label: string;
  year: number;
}

interface Value {
  label: string;
}

export const top100Films: FilmOption[] = [
  { label: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { label: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { label: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { label: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { label: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { label: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { label: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 }
];

export default function AutoComplete({ registerState }) {
  return (
    <HookAutoComplete
      {...registerState("movie")}
      autocompleteProps={{
        options: top100Films,
        autoHighlight: true,
        isOptionEqualToValue: ({ label }: FilmOption, value: Value) =>
          label === value.label
      }}
      textFieldProps={{
        label: "Movie",
        placeholder: "The..."
      }}
      gridProps={{
        xs: 12
      }}
      rules={{
        required: {
          message: "Required",
          value: true
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew . any Idea what is type of `registerState`

Comment: or in other words what is type of this `AutoComplete({ registerState }) {`

Comment: @user944513 If you cmd + click on the destructured `registerState` value from `useHookForm` it should take you to the function declaration, i.e. the type declaration. It looks like `registerState: (name: FieldPath<TFieldValues>) => { control: Control<TFieldValues, TContext>; formState: FormState<TFieldValues>; name: import("react-hook-form").Path<TFieldValues>; setValue: UseFormSetValue<TFieldValues>; trigger: UseFormTrigger<TFieldValues>; };` It's not very readable in the comments here. I also don't think this will help with the `autocompleteProps` prop of the `HookAutoComplete` component.

Comment: sorry for late replay . Thanks for answering .. actually I am using like this 
`export const BookingDetails: React.FC = ({registerState}) => {` i don't want to use `any` keyword

Comment: I go to github I see this code.. ` const registerState = useCallback(
  (name: FieldPath<TFieldValues>) => {
   return {
    control,
    formState,
    name,
    setValue,
    trigger,
   };
  },
  [control, formState, setValue, trigger]
 );`

Comment: @user944513 Ah, yeah, then you may need to declare that type declaration yourself or dig in the source to see if it's also exported for use.